# Upload file to Bitbucket via PHP script

Tags: php, file-upload, curl, bitbucket

I try to upload my database to bitbucket downloads section of my repository via a PHP script using curl library. Normally i go to my phpmyadmin and export my database to a folder, then going to my bitbucket account under downloads section of my repository and upload manually. I need a script that automates these tasks.

I tried using curl library like this:

```
// bitbucket username and password
define('USERNAME', 'my_username');
define('PASSWORD', 'my_password');

$url = 'https://bbuseruploads.s3.amazonaws.com/';
//This needs to be the full path to the file you want to send.
$file_name_with_full_path = realpath('apache_pb2.gif');

$post = array('extra_info' => '123456', 'file_contents' => '@' . $file_name_with_full_path); // image file example here

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, USERNAME . ":" . PASSWORD);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
$resp = curl_exec($ch);

// validate CURL status
if (curl_errno($ch))
  throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), 500);
```

The result:

```
<error><code>InvalidArgument</code>
<message>Unsupported Authorization Type</message>
<argumentvalue>Basic hash_code_here</argumentvalue>
<argumentname>Authorization</argumentname>
<requestid>hash_code_here</requestid>
<hostid>hash_code_here</hostid>
</error>
```

If you need further clarifications please let me know.

Comment: have you got a solutions to this?

Comment: no but now i use pipelines

Answer (score 0):

Just for the case someone finds this old corpse here:

I solved it by this funktion function:

```
 /**
 * Uploads a file to Bitbucket Download area of the configured repository
 * Does the same as thi bash command:
 * curl -X POST "https://USER:PW@api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/owner/slug/downloads/" --form files=@"test.txt"
 * @param string $filename
 * @param string $apiEndpoint
 * @param string $apiUser
 * @param string $apiPassword
 * @return bool|string
 * @throws Deployer\Exception\Exception
 */
public static function sendFileToDownload(
    string $filename,
    string $apiEndpoint,
    string $apiUser,
    string $apiPassword
) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $apiEndpoint);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLAUTH_BASIC, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$apiUser:$apiPassword");

    $data = [
        'files' => curl_file_create($filename),
    ];

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    $erg = curl_exec($curl);
    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ($erg === false || $status > 300) {
        throw new Deployer\Exception\Exception("Result: ".print_r($erg, true), $status);
    }
    curl_close($curl);
  }
}
```

For me the most important point was this section:

```
$data = [
    'files' => curl_file_create($filename),
];
```

This results in a local file been uploaded to my repos download area with the name $filename (filename path).

Answer (score 0):

Had this same problem today. "Unsupported Authorization Type" response from an API CURL request.

I spent a long time consulting with Google. In the end, I discovered that my URL had two slashes in it together (accidentally). See, the API I'm connecting to has a URL, and then an API endpoint. Like this:
https://www.example.com/api/v2/foo -or-
https://www.example.com/api/v2/bar

But I accidentally was combining them like this:
`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url ."/". $endpoint);`
given my data:
`$url        = "https://www.example.com/api/v2/"`
`$endpoint   = "foo"`

I ended up with this:
`"https://www.example.com/api/v2//foo"`

Problem solved by removing the `."/".` and just making it this: `.`

BONUS POSSIBILITY: Something else interesting I learned in the process was that the API folks prefer double-quotes around json data posted to them. I haven't verified it makes a difference, but instead of wrapping double-quotes in single-quotes (or visa-versa), escaping the internal double-quotes is how I left things. And it's working.